# jQuery clone() + appendTo() causing images to break

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload

I am trying to clone a hidden div element and replace the 'body' content with the clone'd html content but the .png images break in the process. They render as broken images with 0px x 0px width n height.

If I check the hidden div before cloning it the images show.

I am more interested in why this is happening than a hack on how to fix it, but hacks are welcome as well.

This only occurs inside Chrome, and does not occur with FireFox.

Here is my entire script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(event) {
     window.onbeforeunload = null;

     var html = jQuery('#ff_exit_popup').clone(); 
     html.show();    
     jQuery('body').empty();
     html.appendTo(jQuery('body'));     


     return "custom message here";


 });


});
```

Comment: There are restrictions on what you're allowed to do inside a `beforeunload` handler.

Comment: BTW, `window.beforeunload = null;` won't remove the jQuery binding. You should use `$(window).off("beforeunload")`.